# Chrome extension: How to capture popup message after filling form automatically from background.js?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension - it automatically fills a certain web form multiple times. Background.js sends messages to content.js, which is working fine. The website pops up a message, like "Form submitted. Reference number is ..." after submitting a form, and I want to capture all these messages. How to achieve this?

background.js

```js
window.popups = []
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type === "myType") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "https://www.example.com/form"
        }, function(tab) {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
            if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
              chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener)
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"msg":"hello"}, function(res){})
            }
          })
        })
      }else if(request.type === "popup"){
        const msg = request.msg
        window.popups.push(msg)
      }
  }
```

I want to call this getPopup function after submitting each form.

```
function getPopup(){
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
            function(tabs){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {'type':'submitted'}, readPopupArr)
            }
        )
    }
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.something){

    }else if(request.type == "submitted"){
        let msg = $(".someclass").text()
                msg = msg.replace("OK", "");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          type:"popup", msg:msg
        })
    }

})
```